# Bug in my floating point code, or gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point

The following code works as expected for me under 64-bits, but fails under 32-bit at -O2 and -O3, the expected output is 1.1, under the bugged systems it prints 1.0.  I'm trying to establish if this is a bug in my code (making some bad assumptions about how floats work) or in GCC.  If it's in my code, how on earth do I go about fixing it?

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int f(double x) {
    return isinf(1.0 / x);
}

int m_isinf(double x) {
    return x != 0 && x * 0.5 == x;
}

int g(double x) {
    return m_isinf(1.0 / x);
}

double values[] = {
    5.5e-309,
    -1.0
};

int main() {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; values[i] != -1.0; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", f(values[i]));
        printf("%d\n", g(values[i]));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expression may be evaluated with more precision than the type.  In your 32 bit build, the compiler is probably using the 80 bits long double (which is no more used in 64 bits) to evaluate `x != 0 && x * 0.5 == x`.

(GCC has know problems with this rules, evaluating with more precisions in context where it can't).

6.3.1.8/2 in C99 (6.2.1.5 in C90 is equivalent):

> The values of floating operands and of the results of floating expressions may be
>   represented in greater precision and range than that required by the type; the types are not
>   changed thereby

In a conforming implementation:

```
int m_isinf(double x) {
    double const half_x = x * 0.5;
    return x != 0 && half_x == x;
}
```

should work. But gcc bug (http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=323 look at the number of duplicates) often prevent this to work.  There are some work around in the bug report.

Comment: Is there a way to write `m_isinf` in a way that's safe against this, without directly checking the bits?

Comment: @Alex, using intermediate variables to ensure that you get the rounding you want is the standard solution. The problem is that gcc's bug often prevent to get the standard behavior. (ISTR that it has been fixed, I don't know at what run-time cost for the program).

Answer (score 2):

Basically, using equality comparison on floats and doubles is a sure way to unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the value directly, like so:

```
#include <math.h>

int isinf(double d) {
  union {
    unsigned long long l;
    double d;
  } u;
  u.d=d;
  return (u.l==0x7FF0000000000000ll?1:u.l==0xFFF0000000000000ll?-1:0);
}
```

Courtesy of dietlibc

Answer (score 0):

Look at this for floating point control http://cibak.web.cern.ch/cibak/pval/valid.html